# Is there a way of preventing a Jenkins string parameter defaulting to the name of the parameter if empty?

Tags: jenkins

I have a string variable in Jenkins that has a default value of an empty string. When I build my job, the value is set to the last part of the parameter name. So our paramater qa-release that was set to an empty string now has a value of release.

Due to the way our code is written, I need to sometimes send in an empty string. We are trying not to install too many plugins so I would prefer a solution that wouldn't require that.
I have tried setting the value to the following, but all produce the above results

- ""
- """"
- "''"
- " "

Comment: have you tried to not set it at all ? or maybe any keywords like NULL or BLANK?

Comment: Yes, it does the same thing if nothing is put in and when null is entered, the value is cleared when the configuration is saved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the **String Parameter**, in the last Jenkins version (but I suppose even from before) you can leave empty the parameter field when you are starting the job, and it results in an empty string value associated to that parameter.

Comment: As I understand, it was fixed only here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45300.

Comment: @evgeny9 I've updated to the latest jenkins, but am still experiencing this supposed-to-be-fixed issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: @lyuboslavkanev, not Jenkins itself, but https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin ("Gradle Plugin - Jenkins - Jenkins Wiki") should be updated.

Comment: @evgeny9 didn't do it for me :\

Comment: @lyuboslavkanev, it's a pity. Then I guess one way is to process this issue in your subsequent code.